# Whats the difference between mounting a partition as a folder with a new drive and creating a volume spanning two drives?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

These two techniques seem a bit redundant. Is there a difference between the two that makes one more suitable for specific scenarios?

I was given the example that if there was no more space on one hard drive, you could mount another one as a folder, and you'd have more space within the folder, but at that point why not just expand the volume?

Comment: Include your question in the question.

Comment: I'm not going to down vote your question but it is unclear as to exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Brian I found it quite easily to understand. See my answer, you may then also understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a partition spanning two drives requires a RAID setup. If you have just 2 drives, and you want the space, as in your example, you need a striped raid configration.

If you rely on a hardware raid controller, you need to create the partition setup before putting any data on it. This cannot be done after you already installed windows on it. Windows can, however also turn a partition into a dynamic disk and then span the partition onto multiple drives, but this places everything inside a container. In either case, you can no longer move that harddisk into another computer without the first one and expect to be able to get data from it.

If you mount a partition as a folder, only that specific folder resides on the other disk. This means that other folders can still easily fill your other drive, so it becomes a mess in where what is stored.

The pros and cons are as follows:
Pros for a RAID striped setup:

- This is a lot faster, as data is read and written to both drives at the same time.
- Your entire partition can be as big as both drives combined, and its not limited to just one drive

Cons for a RAID striped setup:

- Hardware is preferred, but that means it must be setup before you fill the data.
- If one of the disk dies, all data is gone.

Pros for mounting a partition as a folder:

- If your main drive dies, the content of this folder remains in tact
- If your 2nd drive dies, only this folder vanishes.
- It is something you can setup easily
- You can have a driveletter and folder assigned to a partition at the same time.
- Can be done with an external drive, and as such, you can make it a security thing to not have this folder accessible if the disk is not plugged in, then place the disk in a vault.

Cons for mounting a partition as a folder:

- You only move the data from that folder to the other partition, so unless this folder is huge, you're not going to save a lot of space.
- If you do it with lots of folders, it will become a mess, and the fact that you can't resize them later may become an issue if that partition was made too small.
- If your second drive fails, it may not be apparent why that folder is missing, and may make troubleshooting harder in the long run.

So here are the pros and cons of each. It is up to you to decide what you want. I'm not going to give you my opinion because opinions are off-topic here. You have the information to form one of your own. Good luck, and don't forget, you can always buy a bigger harddisk and just migrate all data to the new disk and not have this problem in the first place.

Comment: You said: "Creating a partition spanning two drives requires a RAID setup." That is wrong. In Linux LVM allows you to spann partitions. Other file system integrate device management, such als BTRFS, ZFS or BCacheFS. Even legacy Windows versions allowed for "dynamic disks".

Comment: @r2d3 while true, OP tagged the question NTFS. They're clearly on windows. Listing every possible outcome will be very confusing, that's why I ommitted it.

Comment: Even assuming what you guessed about the operating system used, your statement is wrong in the windows world. You did not read my comment as you are ignoring my point. The issue is not about "listing every outcome".

Comment: But isn't a dynamic disk a raid setup still? RAID stands for Redundand Array of Independent Disks, which is what dynamic disk is and the other solutions are too.

Comment: There is no striping in dynamic disk setups. Striping is a key element of RAID with the exception of RAID 1. If you read descriptions of RAID controller products the manuals or ads typically mention JBOD or RAID configuration. JBOD is like dynamic disks.